# Cypher slow performance for small database

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I am working on a bus schedule search. I create some simple data to test: 10 buses, for each bus there are 2-5 schedules, and each schedule has one location relationship as follows:

```
bus-[:SCHEDULED]->(schedule)-[scheduleLocation :ORIGIN|TRANSIT|DESTINATION]->location
```

I want to search bus runs on Monday at the specified location during a specified time range and I'm wondering why it's taking a long time to run the query(more than 10 seconds).

Here's the query:

```
MATCH bus-[:SCHEDULED]->(schedule)-[scheduleLocation :ORIGIN|TRANSIT|DESTINATION]->location
where location.code! = 'KING' AND 
(
(bus.runsOnMonday = true AND ((specifiedScheduleLocation.arrivalTime! >='+00:00:16:00' OR specifiedScheduleLocation.departTime! >='+00:00:16:00') AND (specifiedScheduleLocation.arrivalTime! <='+00:14:42:00' OR specifiedScheduleLocation.departTime! <='+00:14:42:00')))
OR (bus.runsOnTuesday = true AND ((specifiedScheduleLocation.arrivalTime! >='+06:00:16:00' OR specifiedScheduleLocation.departTime! >='+06:00:16:00') AND (specifiedScheduleLocation.arrivalTime! <='+06:14:41:00' OR specifiedScheduleLocation.departTime! <='+06:14:41:00')))
OR (bus.runsOnWednesday = true AND ((specifiedScheduleLocation.arrivalTime! >='+05:00:16:00' OR specifiedScheduleLocation.departTime! >='+05:00:16:00') AND (specifiedScheduleLocation.arrivalTime! <='+05:14:41:00' OR specifiedScheduleLocation.departTime! <='+05:14:41:00')))
OR (bus.runsOnThursday = true AND ((specifiedScheduleLocation.arrivalTime! >='+04:00:16:00' OR specifiedScheduleLocation.departTime! >='+04:00:16:00') AND (specifiedScheduleLocation.arrivalTime! <='+04:14:41:00' OR specifiedScheduleLocation.departTime! <='+04:14:41:00')))
OR (bus.runsOnFriday = true AND ((specifiedScheduleLocation.arrivalTime! >='+03:00:16:00' OR specifiedScheduleLocation.departTime! >='+03:00:16:00') AND (specifiedScheduleLocation.arrivalTime! <='+03:14:41:00' OR specifiedScheduleLocation.departTime! <='+03:14:41:00')))
OR (bus.runsOnSaturday = true AND ((specifiedScheduleLocation.arrivalTime! >='+02:00:16:00' OR specifiedScheduleLocation.departTime! >='+02:00:16:00') AND (specifiedScheduleLocation.arrivalTime! <='+02:14:41:00' OR specifiedScheduleLocation.departTime! <='+02:14:41:00')))
OR (bus.runsOnSunday = true AND ((specifiedScheduleLocation.arrivalTime! >='+01:00:16:00' OR specifiedScheduleLocation.departTime! >='+01:00:16:00') AND (specifiedScheduleLocation.arrivalTime! <='+01:14:41:00' OR specifiedScheduleLocation.departTime! <='+01:14:41:00')))
)
return distinct bus,specifiedScheduleLocation
```

Comment: Is it because of many conditions?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK queries with where clauses based on properties are slow because Neo4j will have to load all matching nodes/relationships and then scan through their properties to filter them.

For better results you may want to move properties into nodes and relationships and try to find your results just by filtering paths based on relationship paths and node labels.

Perhaps the most obvious example is the use of time trees instead of timestamp properties ([link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/neo4j-cypher-creating-time)).

If you don't need to manage specific dates, just day of the week and times, you could have a 24 hour time tree for each day of the week.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Looks like this is a good way to try.

Answer (score 0):

Does location have a label? If not, please give it a label `Location`, then run

`CREATE INDEX ON :Location(code)`

Wait a few seconds/minutes (depending on the size of the db).

Then change the query to:

```
MATCH bus-[:SCHEDULED]->(schedule)-[scheduleLocation :ORIGIN|TRANSIT|DESTINATION]->(location:Location {code:'KING'})
where (
(bus.runsOnMonday = true AND ((specifiedScheduleLocation.arrivalTime! >='+00:00:16:00' OR specifiedScheduleLocation.departTime! >='+00:00:16:00') AND (specifiedScheduleLocation.arrivalTime! <='+00:14:42:00' OR specifiedScheduleLocation.departTime! <='+00:14:42:00')))
OR (bus.runsOnTuesday = true AND ((specifiedScheduleLocation.arrivalTime! >='+06:00:16:00' OR specifiedScheduleLocation.departTime! >='+06:00:16:00') AND (specifiedScheduleLocation.arrivalTime! <='+06:14:41:00' OR specifiedScheduleLocation.departTime! <='+06:14:41:00')))
OR (bus.runsOnWednesday = true AND ((specifiedScheduleLocation.arrivalTime! >='+05:00:16:00' OR specifiedScheduleLocation.departTime! >='+05:00:16:00') AND (specifiedScheduleLocation.arrivalTime! <='+05:14:41:00' OR specifiedScheduleLocation.departTime! <='+05:14:41:00')))
OR (bus.runsOnThursday = true AND ((specifiedScheduleLocation.arrivalTime! >='+04:00:16:00' OR specifiedScheduleLocation.departTime! >='+04:00:16:00') AND (specifiedScheduleLocation.arrivalTime! <='+04:14:41:00' OR specifiedScheduleLocation.departTime! <='+04:14:41:00')))
OR (bus.runsOnFriday = true AND ((specifiedScheduleLocation.arrivalTime! >='+03:00:16:00' OR specifiedScheduleLocation.departTime! >='+03:00:16:00') AND (specifiedScheduleLocation.arrivalTime! <='+03:14:41:00' OR specifiedScheduleLocation.departTime! <='+03:14:41:00')))
OR (bus.runsOnSaturday = true AND ((specifiedScheduleLocation.arrivalTime! >='+02:00:16:00' OR specifiedScheduleLocation.departTime! >='+02:00:16:00') AND (specifiedScheduleLocation.arrivalTime! <='+02:14:41:00' OR specifiedScheduleLocation.departTime! <='+02:14:41:00')))
OR (bus.runsOnSunday = true AND ((specifiedScheduleLocation.arrivalTime! >='+01:00:16:00' OR specifiedScheduleLocation.departTime! >='+01:00:16:00') AND (specifiedScheduleLocation.arrivalTime! <='+01:14:41:00' OR specifiedScheduleLocation.departTime! <='+01:14:41:00')))
)
return distinct bus,specifiedScheduleLocation
```

Finally, please let us know if it helped! It should, because your current query scans the entire graph - it has not concrete node to anchor on.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for you answer. The database is quite small and only have some test data. I do create index for location code. But this doesn't help much. I found the other queries are working fine except this kind of queries with this set of timing conditions.